# Adding more text to d3 pie chart on mouseover event

Tags: javascript, d3.js, mouseover

I am trying to figure out how to show more text on a pie chart using `mouseover` than just the data that is bound to the pie. Below is my functional code

```
function Pie(value,names){

svg.selectAll("g.arc").remove()

var outerRadius = 100;
        var innerRadius = 0;
        var arc = d3.svg.arc()
                .innerRadius(innerRadius)
                .outerRadius(outerRadius);

    var pie = d3.layout.pie();
    var color = d3.scale.category10();
    var arcs = svg.selectAll("g.arc")
              .data(pie(value))
              .enter()
              .append("g")
              .attr("class", "arc")
              .attr("transform", "translate(950,80)");

    arcs.append("path")
            .attr("fill", function(d, i) {
                return color(i);
            })
            .attr("d", arc)
            .on("mouseover",function(d,i) {
             arcs.append("text")
                .attr("dy", ".5em")
                .style("text-anchor", "middle")
                .style("fill", function(d,i){return "black";})
                .text(d.data)
            })

            .on("mouseout", function(d) {

                arcs.select("text").remove();
            });}
```

The `names` array has the same length as the `value` array which is passed to the pie. I really hoped that something like this would work by replacing the above `mouseover`.

```
.on("mouseover",function(d,i) {
             arcs.append("text")
                .attr("dy", ".5em")
                .style("text-anchor", "middle")
                .style("fill", function(d,i){return "black";})
                .text(function(d,i){return (d.data +" " + names[i]);)
            })
```

But the only thing it does is to show all the elements of the `values` array stacked one on top of the other and the last element of the `names` array. It seems that `i` is always the last index in this case. How would I go about that? Could I show the text I want in another way? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, the variable `arcs` is a data-bound d3 selection which represents all the arcs of the pie.  So, by calling `arcs.append`, you are going to append a `text` element for each piece of your pie chart.  I think you mean to only append one `text` element based on what you moused-over so re-write that as:

```
svg.append('text')
  ...
```

Second, in this expression:

```
.text(function(d,i){return (d.data +" " + names[i]);)
```

`d` and `i` in the **mouseover function** already represent the data and index of the pie slice being moused over.  There is no reason to wrap this in another function and should be re-written:

```
.text(d.data +" " + names[i]);
```

Here's a complete example:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>
  body {
    font: 10px sans-serif;
  }
  
  .arc path {
    stroke: #fff;
  }
</style>

<body>
  <script src="//d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    var width = 960,
      height = 500,
      radius = Math.min(width, height) / 2;

    var color = d3.scale.category10();

    var arc = d3.svg.arc()
      .outerRadius(radius - 10)
      .innerRadius(0);

    var pie = d3.layout.pie()
      .sort(null)
      .value(function(d) {
        return d.value;
      });

    var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
      .attr("width", width)
      .attr("height", height)
      .append("g")
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")");

    var data = [{
      value: Math.random(),
    }, {
      value: Math.random(),
    }, {
      value: Math.random(),
    }, {
      value: Math.random(),
    }, {
      value: Math.random(),
    }]
    
    var names = ["A","B","C","D","E"];

    var arcs = svg.selectAll(".arc")
      .data(pie(data))
      .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "arc");

    arcs.append("path")
      .attr("d", arc)
      .style("fill", function(d,i) {
        return color(i);
      })
      .on("mouseover", function(d, i) {
          console.log(d);
          svg.append("text")
            .attr("dy", ".5em")
            .style("text-anchor", "middle")
            .style("font-size", 45)
            .attr("class","label")
            .style("fill", function(d,i){return "black";})
            .text(names[i]);
          
      })
      .on("mouseout", function(d) {
        svg.select(".label").remove();
      });
    
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: That is what I was looking for. Thank you so much.